Calling the salt python api on window server2019, accessing the minion configuration file reports an error PermissionError: [Errno 13]
I tried to get the minion's master IP through salt-call --local grains.item master on the minion, but it reported an error. I also got the same error when I tried it in the python shell.
Python 3.10.14 (heads/main:c1ec015, Apr  3 2024, 21:36:37) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import salt.config
>>>  opts=salt.config.minion_config("C:\ProgramData\Salt Project\Salt\conf")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    opts=salt.config.minion_config("C:\ProgramData\Salt Project\Salt\conf")
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> opts=salt.config.minion_config("C:\ProgramData\Salt Project\Salt\conf")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt\Lib\site-packages\salt\config\__init__.py", line 2306, in minion_config
    overrides = load_config(path, env_var, DEFAULT_MINION_OPTS["conf_file"])
  File "C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt\Lib\site-packages\salt\config\__init__.py", line 2138, in load_config
    opts = _read_conf_file(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt\Lib\site-packages\salt\config\__init__.py", line 2025, in _read_conf_file
    with salt.utils.files.fopen(path, "r") as conf_file:
  File "C:\Program Files\Salt Project\Salt\Lib\site-packages\salt\utils\files.py", line 388, in fopen
    f_handle = open(  # pylint: disable=resource-leakage,unspecified-encoding
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Salt Project\\Salt\\conf'


I tried to run it as an administrator, but got the same error. I checked the file properties of C:\ProgramData\Salt Project\Salt, which showed that owner rights, system, and administrator all had full access control permissions. The user running the salt-minion service also belongs to the administrator group.
salt version: 3007.1
I am not familiar with window permission control, and I am not sure if this is because Salt has special permission control on its files. In addition, I can edit and modify the minion configuration file directly, but I cannot use salt-call and python shell. How can I solve the permission problem? Or is there any way for me to obtain the master IP?
